# Notification on deleted/held questions

Tags: discussion

Is there supposed to be a notification if a question you are participating (and awarded reputation) in is deleted? A couple of time I've seen my rep change, but there's no indication as to why.

- Is it normal to lose/gain rep on a deleted/held question?
- Should there be some indication as to the rep change?

Comment: You can see your gains and losses in details here: https://askubuntu.com/users/current/?tab=reputation I am not sure I get your point on the rest. If a question is remove and with it your contribution, you will lose the rep you got from that contribution, this is not true if a question is just closed. Is that what you needed to know?

Comment: Interesting...when I checked last night, nothing had shown up; maybe there's just a delay when this happens. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: There is a delay for the system cache. This will tell you all about it and why it works that way https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178596/what-is-caching-and-where-is-it-used

Comment: Perfect - thanks again.